# How does postgrey track inbound mail

Tags: email, postfix

I need to understand how postgrey keeps track of inbound mail. I know the concept of how greylisting works, but I'm wondering about the actual method. Greylisting will count the number of times a mail server has sent through a message succesfully over a given period of time and if it reaches the desired threshold, it will become a known mail host for X amount of time.

I understand that.

But if a specific mail comes in for the first time, from an unknown mail host, how does postgrey keep track of this individual message - i.e. when it comes back from a compliant server the second time, how does postgrey know it was a "deferred" mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising the behaviour: the check is made against IP address+sender+receiver.
The connection states are kept in a Berkeley DB.

When connection arrives:

- if it part of a defined whitelist it is accepted;
- if not in the DB, it is added to the DB and the connection is rejected;
- if in the DB:

  - if it is the first retrial it is beyond the retry_window, it is discared from the DB;
  - if it is in the defined retry_window, the connection will then be accepted.

From [Greylisting to avoid spam](https://arnowelzel.de/en/greylisting-to-avoid-spam)

> The triplet of ip address, sender and receiver will now be stored to
>   the database of postgrey as “known sender” and further mails from the
>   same address should by delivered immediately without any delay.
>
> Since the most spammers don’t to this – try the delivery a second time
>   – most spam mails will just be ignored.

From [posgrey source comments](https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/postgrey__schweikert/blob/master/postgrey)

> find out if the last time was unsuccessful, so that we can add a
>   header to say how much had to be waited.
>   ....
>   discard stored first-seen
>   if it is the first retrial and it is beyond the retry_window.

Comment: Thanks, Rui! So, using this logic, it would be possible to manually resend a mail and it should then pass if it's within the retry window (say 5 minutes)? Or in this case, send two emails in succession and the second mail should go through immediately, even if it has a different subject, for example?

Comment: And also following this logic, if the retry-window is set to 5 minutes and the sending server retries only after 10 minutes each time, the mail would never get delivered?

Comment: Yes to all questions, I think. I am not seeing the subject of the message being tracked on the sources.